# why is a strpos that is !== false not true?

Tags: php, boolean, strpos, stripos

Consider the following example:

```
$a='This is a test';
```

If I now do:

```
if(strpos($a,'is a') !== false) {
    echo 'True';
}
```

It get:

```
True
```

However, if I use

```
if(strpos($a,'is a') === true) {
    echo 'True';
}
```

I get nothing. Why is `!==false` not `===true` in this context
I checked the PHP docs on `strpos()` but did not find any explanation on this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: if you were to take `=== true` out, you'd get your "true" statement, because `strpos` would return a 1 and not a zero --  IE `if(strpos($a,'is a'){`

Comment: The `===` is looking for a `bool` set to `true` --  And while a 1 is *technically* `true` -- It's not *literally* `true`  --- And `===` is looking for a *literal* comparison

Comment: Pete, does @Zak's message make sense to you? I think your question shows that you might be struggling with truthy vs true and falsy vs false.

Comment: Yes, I think I did not know that a positive integer (which is was strpos delivers if it finds the string) does not equate to true in the === sense but only in the == sense. Eventually Barmar's reply to my comment in the answer below about type conversions cleared it up. This should really be in the php manual on strpos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Because `strpos()` never returns true](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

It only returns a boolean if the needle is not found. Otherwise it will return an integer, [including -1 and 0](https://3v4l.org/JVnD0), with the position of the occurrence of the needle.

If you had done:

```
if(strpos($a,'is a') == true) {
    echo 'True';
}
```

You would have *usually* gotten expected results as any positive integer is considered a truthy value and because type juggling when you use the `==` operator that result would be true. *But* if the string was at the start of the string it would equate to false due to zero being return which is a falsey value.

Comment: ah OK. I thought a positive integer would also count as true.

Comment: @pete, it does. But this function also returns zero which is `false`

Comment: @Pete When you use `===`, there's no type conversion. If the values are different types, they can never be `===`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for these clarifications. It was not clear to me from the php manual.

Comment: Are you saying `strpos` may return `-1`…!?

Answer (score 0):

The strpos function returns an integer value on success and  false only if the needle was not found in the string. In our case, the string 'This is a test' contains 'is a'. So the test (position)!==false [where position is the first occurence of 'is a'] is different from false in both type and value and will return true.